# Rails ActiveRecord association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `user` and `card` and i want to establish an association in which `user has_many :cards` but cards can be viewed by all. So `card belongs_to :user` but anyone else can view them.

How do i set this association in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not really complicated, just do the association you describe:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, :dependent => :destroy #so when you delete a user, his cards will be deleted
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # The cards table must have the column "user_id", just do a migration to add it
end

# The migration would be something like:
def change
  add_column :cards, :user_id, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false

  add_index :cards, :user_id #it's better to add an index cause you'll surely often get cards from user_id
end
```

**Edit: some explanations on the "null => false" constraint, and ":default => 0"**

The "not null" constraint will prevent cards from not belonging to users. So a card must have an associated user! If it shouldn't always be that way, then just remove the ":null => false" constraint.

The default => 0 is there to set a default value to user_id for the already created cards. Otherwise it will raise an error if you let the ":null => false" constraint. Of course you'll then have to delete those cards or to set properly their "user_id" attribute.

---

Then, don't forget that to create a card that belongs to a user, you'll have to do it that way: `new_card = current_user.cards.build`, this code will automatically fill in the "user_id" attribute with the "current_user.id" value.

Then to get the cards of a user just do: `current_user.cards` (where current_user is the user viewing it's profile). 
And to get all the cards, regardless of the user, just do: `Card.all`

If you want to filter access to some cards, you'll have to do it in your controllers, this has nothing to do with associations ;) Making an association between cards and users won't have any effect on accessing objects from the Card model.

Comment: so why should i make a belongs_to :user at all? maybe just declare that user has_many cards?

Comment: and also should i add a migration also to the user model? card_id?

Comment: You have to add a "belongs_to :user" because thanks to that you'll be able to find which user the card belongs to. It'll be usefull, for instance, if you want to be able to make a link from a card to a user profile so that other users may access the card's creator public profile. Also has_many and belongs_to often work together, and they both bring useful methods. You should look at this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html to see all the methods they will give you.

Comment: @i'm getting this: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL: ALTER TABLE "cards" ADD "user_id" integer NOT NULL

Comment: And nop, you won't have to add the "card_id" column to your user model, because one user "HAS MANY" cards, so when you do: user.cards, the query to the database will get the cards filtered by the user id.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't think you already created some cards. I'll edit my answer. ;)

Comment: view my previous comments. something is wrong with the  :null => false

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set an association between the two models. Just make sure your viewing action (could be named `index`) would view all the cards.

Comment: But i want to let a user, say, view the cards he made in the past in his profile page

Comment: if you use `Cards.all` you will get all the cards, is that what you want ?

Comment: no. i want Cards.all to view all the cards but also, when a user goes to his profile then he would see the specific cards he made

Comment: ok then in the action for the user profile, use `user.cards` this will return only the cards he made.